# Getting type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Response>' in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, testing, mockito, client

I'm trying to run a text in flutter using mockito but I have been getting a error of

```
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Response>'
```

Below is the code

```
class MockClient extends Mock implements http.Client {}

void main() {
  var client = MockClient();
  var sut = AuthApi('http:baseUrl', client);

  setUp(() {
    client;
    sut;
  });
  group('signin', () {
    var credential = Credential(
      type: AuthType.email,
      email: 'email@email',
      password: 'pass',
    );
    test('should return error when status is not 200', () async {
      when(client.post(Uri(), body: anyNamed('body')))
          .thenAnswer((_) async => http.Response('{}', 404));

      var result = await sut.signIn(credential);

     expect(result, isA<ErrorResult>());
    });
  });
}
```

I have tried to pass

```
when(client.post(any, body: anyNamed('body')))
```

but I got any error of: The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'

Answer (score 0):

Since Mockito migrated to a null safety code, you need to Override the method with a new declaration inside the mock class. At a body of the override method call `super.noSuchMethod`, passing in an Invocation object which includes all of the values passed to the override, and pass a second argument to `super.noSuchMethod`, a value which can function as a return value.

Here is an example:

```
class MockClient extends Mock implements http.Client {
   @override
   Future<http.Response> post(Uri uri, {String body}) => super.noSuchMethod(Invocation.method(#post, [uri, body]), returnValue: http.Response('{}', 404));
}
```

Please note that your method parameters may be different

Comment: I appreciate your effort you took to explain, but I am actually learning using a tutorial so I honestly don't know probably don't understand but I tried and this is the error I got.
```MockClient.post ('Future<Response> Function(Uri, {required String body})') isn't a valid override of Client.post ```

Comment: Yes, that is why I mentioned that your method parameters may be different. It also may be because of a return type of a overridden method. What you actually need to do is check original Client.post method signature (return type and all parameters), and add everything to the overridden method too.